# How do I play sound with (IBAction)playsound:(id)sender

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, audio

I am trying to simply place a sound with its button. I have reached a stopping point due to the lack of understanding. I tried for about 4 hours trying to fix this but, to no avail found nothing. can someone help me? I'm getting the error, "**use of undeclared identifier 'soundFile**'" here is my .m file..

```
//
//  FirstViewController.m
//  simpleApp
//
//  Created by Abby Russell on 11/29/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Abby Russell. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playsound:(id)sender {
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *buttonName=[sender currentTitle];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:buttonName ofType:@"wav"];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)
                                     [NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundFile], &
                                     soundID;
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);


}
@end
```

Thank you so much smart people!

Comment: There is no need to down vote. It is a legitimate question from a beginner. Remember what it was like when you began.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

soundFile needs to be an NSString path to the sound file. It appears you just entered the text "soundFile" without actually having any NSString named soundFile. Try replacing soundFile with "path".

Comment: This worked! oh my I feel silly for asking this question. Maybe I should get some fresh air...  Thank you so much